# Android Singleton and memory problems

Tags: android, memory, singleton

I'm having problems with my singletons in my Android app. I've read all post here in Stackoverflow about this issue but I'm confuse about it.

I have a singleton to represent an interface with other system. Its structure is something like this:

```
public class Ifc
{
    private static Ifc sharedIfc;
    private String attrib;

    public static Ifc getInstance()
    {
        if (sharedIfc == null)
        {
            sharedIfc = new Ifc();
            sharedIfc.attrib = "";
        }
        return sharedIfc;
     }

     public boolean isMyAttrib(String myAttrib)
     {
         if(this.attrib.matches(myAttrib)) 
             return true;
         else
             return false;
     }
}
```

And I access this singleton this way:

```
myIfcInstance = Ifc.getInstance();
boolean _isMyAttrib = myIfcInstance.isMyAttrib("example");
```

My problem is that this code is not working properly running in devices with low memory problems. In these devices the app crashes very often in line "if(this.attrib.matches(myAttrib))" with NullPointer error in attrib.

I know that is possible that static data are removed from the memory in low memory scenarios but is it possible that the class is not null but its attributes are null?

And what is the best way to avoid this? Maybe something like that? I think is awful, but it could work:

```
    public static Ifc getInstance()
    {
        if (sharedIfc == null)
        {
            sharedIfc = new Ifc();
            sharedIfc.attrib = "";
        }
        if(shared.attrib == null) shared.attrib = "";
        return sharedIfc;
     }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way that data is guaranteed by the Android API to be around for the life time of the app that is creating a class that extends Application. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

For complete transparence I have seen android engineers recommending the us of singletons instead, however this method has always worked perfect for me for application critical data and objects.

After you create a class extending Application you can get a reference from any part of your application as follows

```
myClass app = (myClass)getApplication();
```

In the "myClass" class you can do the same methods you would implement in your singleton implementation above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I didn't see this answer because my customer finally decided to ignore this problem since it happened only to very few Android models and in very specific moments.

Comment: No problem, at least it might help you in future projects :)

Comment: Link you provided says there is no need to extend Application, but rather use static Singletons instead...(?)

Comment: Hey @JohnyTex, this answer is very old, so I am sure that it was different at the time. 10 years on I will say be careful of singletons as they make code a lot harder to test.